# Alternate Proof to Group Theory Proof?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

This is the proof from the textbook.
[image: From Abstract Algebra by Judson]

Is this a valid proof? Let $G$ be a group. $ax = b$ such that $a \in G$ and $b \in G$. Our goal is to show that $x \in G$ is unique for any arbitrary $a$ and $b$.

Let's define a function $f: G \to G$ given by $ax$. We will show that this function is injective. Let's assume that $x'\in G$, then $ax' = ax$ iff $f$ is an injective function. If we left multiply both sides by $a^{-1}$, then we obtain $x = x'$. Because $f$ is an injective function, it is clear that there can only be one $x$ that maps to any arbitrary $b$ thus showing that $x$ is unique.

Comment: “Suppose $ax=b.$ We must show such an $x$ exists.” That is very odd phrasing. The writer literally just supposed $x$ exists.

Comment: yeah ikr, here's the textbook for reference. http://abstract.pugetsound.edu/aata/section-groups-define.html

Comment: Your alternate proof, using injective function, does show uniqueness. Essentially, this theorem is saying $f$ is a bijection.

Comment: awesome thanks, any other suggestions? I'll delete the question if not. Don't want to clutter up the forum.

Comment: The book's proof doesn't prove existence, but it proves uniqueness twice. Your proof is essentially the same as the book's second proof of uniqueness.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "prove uniqueness twice". It seems that first paragraph writes $x$ in terms of $a^{-1}$ and $b$ which we know exist from the problem statement. How is this not showing existence? Moreover, how is it showing uniqueness?

Comment: Please do not rely on images to convey relevant information. [Here's an explanation of why this is frowned upon](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/742).

Comment: It proves uniqueness twice by first proving that if a solution exists then it is necessarily unique and equal to $a^{-1}b$. Then it proves uniqueness again by proving any two solutions are equal. It never actually verifies that $a^{-1}b$ *is* a solution. It's a similar problem to the fact that if a matrix $A$ has a left inverse $B$ that is not a right inverse, and if $Ax=b$ has a solution, then the solution is $Bb$... but there may be no solution at all.

Comment: To actually prove existence, it should *verify* that the element $a^{-1}b$ does actually solve the equation. All they did was show that if there is a solution at all, it must be that... but maybe there is no solution?

Comment: Could we just plug in $x=a^{-1}b$ to show existence?

Comment: Yes, but you have to actually do so. Your quote does not, and instead simply *assumes* that a solution exists; so they never prove existence, they just prove that if a solution exists, then it is equal to $a^{-1}b$.